# Find 2 Dates A DateTime Falls between From Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary where the key is a DateTime. I need to find the 2 entries in the dictionary that are closest to a given datetime.

So, I have

```
Dictionary<DateTime, double> columnInfos = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
foreach (var activity in activities)
{

    DateTime activityDate = activity.ActivityDateTime;

    // Get the 2 entries in the columnInfos dict that activityDate falls between

}
```

I was going to loop through the dictionary, but is that really the best way?> Anyone have a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: `but is that really the best way?` How would you test all the values in the dictionary without looping through them?

Comment: I suppose you can treat the dictionary as a sorted list and use a binary search to find where your value falls in that list.  For large lists that would work better than a loop.  For small lists it may not make enough of a difference to merit the extra complexity.

Comment: Depending on your implementation, it may be easier to use a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) and apply a binary search.

Comment: But using a SortedDictionary would only find me one match. I need the 2 DateTime the search value falls between

Comment: Depends on how you use the SortedDictionary, you just need to find the spot in the dictionary that your date falls in between (where it falls in the order), and extract the date before and after.

Comment: @AzNjoE, can you provide an example? I'm just not seeing it

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your `Dictionary<T, T>` to a `SortedDictionary<T, T>`, you can write a function like this:

```
private List<DateTime> FallBetween(SortedDictionary<DateTime, double> columns, DateTime activityDate)
{
    var keys = new List<DateTime>(columns.Keys);
    int index = ~(keys.BinarySearch(activityDate));

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    try
    {
        dates.Add(keys[index]);
    } catch { }

    try
    {
        dates.Add(keys[index - 1]);
    } catch { }

    return dates;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, double> columnInfos = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>();

columnInfos.Add(DateTime.Now, 1);
columnInfos.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), 2);
columnInfos.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4), 3);
columnInfos.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), 4);
columnInfos.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4), 5);

// dates will return a list containing two dates.
// Now - 2 days and Now - 4 days.
var dates = FallBetween(columnInfos, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3));

// date will return a list containing only one date
// because there is only one nearing neighbor.
var date = FallBetween(columnInfos, DateTime.Now.AddDays(30));
```

Comment: This always returns one element

Comment: @CoderForHire -- Double check. The first example, `dates` returns 2 for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. `index-1` and `index+1` will be the position in the list of the dates immediately less than and greater than the date in question.

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, double> columnInfos = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, double>();

List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>> columnInfosList = columnInfos.ToList();

foreach (var activity in activities)
{
    DateTime activityDate = activity.ActivityDateTime;

    for (int index = 1; index < columnInfosList.Count(); index++)
    {
         if (columnInfosList[index-1].Key < activityDate && columnInfosList[index+1].Key > activityDate)
         {
              // do something with columnInfos[index-1] and columnInfos[index+1] then break so you stop searching
         }
    }
}
```